# Redirect any URL that doesn't exists in my server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've made a DNS change in my client's former domain, so now all the URLs that are like ABCDEF.com are now translated into UVWXYZ.com, but my client wants to maintain every link to his page and I'm doing a good set of 301 redirects via htaccess and mod_rewrite. So now my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^list.aspx?i=5$ list.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cat.aspx?i=1$ printers.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cat.aspx?i=3$ multi.php [R=301,L]
```

in this moment, when I enter ABCDEF.com/list.aspx my browser loads UVWXYZ.com/list.php (and so with the other examples) but my client wants to redirect any other page to the home page. In other words, when I enter ABCDEF.com/downloads.aspx my browser must load UVWXYZ.com.

I've tried rules like

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [R=301,L]
```

but the server shouts a redirection loop. Which rule would fits my case best?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Google suggests displaying a 404 error page and returning a 404 status code rather than redirecting to a home page, this would be worth discussing with your client from an SEO stand point

Comment: my client sees himself as a SEO guru, but i'll try to tell him more information about what Google suggests. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try one of these:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Or:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Or with just mod_rewrite (at the very end of your htaccess file):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L,R=301]
```